# Multiple bodies and coordinate systems

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems

Say we have a pulley with two masses attached, say $m$ and $M$, and they both accelerate at the same rate but in opposite directions, why can we solve the two equations of motion simultaneously if the equations of motion for each mass are written with respect to different coordinate systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

to solve this problem you choose two  inertial system $~y_M~,y_m$
assume the mass M goes down

the equations are:

$$\sum F_M=M\,\ddot y_M+T-M\,g=0\\
\sum F_m=m\,\ddot y_m+m\,g-T=0$$
and the constrained equation

$$ y_M+y_m-L=0\quad\Rightarrow \ddot y_M+\ddot y_m=0$$

you obtain 3 equations for the 3 unknowns  $~\ddot y_M~,\ddot y_m~,T$

thus the results $~a_M=g~,a_m=-g~,T=0$

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

You can conceptualise a coordinate systems as a frame to see the world in. For instance a metaphor would be the glasses we wear. Now, in a given frame we can assign things like position and velocity to different objects.

Each object would have their own pair of position and velocity variables $(x_i,v_i)$.

One interesting point is that due to assumption of Newton's mechanics, the time experienced in any frame would be same.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't really answer my question, could you please walk me through an example, say if we had two masses of 2 and 5 kg each respectively on a smooth light pulley with a light inextensible string.

Comment: This would be to calculate the instantaneous acceleration of each mass the instant the system is released from rest.

Comment: Consider a x-y coordinate system centered at the pulley disc center. Now let y_1 be position of one mass and y_2 be the other. We can also write whole system jn one variable due to conservation of string y_1+y_2+pir= constant. The rpi comes from string lying on top perimeter of disc